# phpmyadmin отображается php код вместо самой страницы

Tags: phpmyadmin, apache2, lamp

установил lamp, все встало, но при переходе на http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ отображается php код (((([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: хотя MySQL monitor работает отлично, коннект есть

Answer (score -1):

всем у кого эта проблема - sudo apt-get install php-mbstring и усе :)

Comment: причин у этой проблемы может быть полно, не всем может подойти. У вас может вообще php не было, а вы его подтянули из зависимостей для mbstring ;)